# Populating a Two-Dimansional Array From CSV Data

Tags: java, arrays, csv, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I want to assign data in a CSV data file into a two-dimension array. I've written the following code but it only works for 1D arrays. As soon as I add extra square brackets to the below line, an error occurs. I'm really new to Java. Please help.

```
String[] pTEDATA = line.split(cvsSplitBy); // Before
String[][] pTEDATA = line.split(cvsSplitBy); // After
```

**Here's the entire code:**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class pTE {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

  pTE obj = new pTE();
obj.run();

  }

  public void run() {

String csvFile = "C:/Users/marathnayake/Downloads/new.csv";
BufferedReader br = null;
String line = "";
String cvsSplitBy = ",";

try {

    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if(line.equals("")){
            continue;
        }
        String[][] pTEDATA = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

        //while (pTEDATA != null){
            //System.out.println("[\'" + pTEDATA[0] + "\'], " + "[\'" + pTEDATA[1] + "\'], " + "[\'" + pTEDATA[2] + "\']" );    
        //}

    }

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (br != null) {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using split method of string which returns 1D array. One thing that you can do is split the line and get 1D array and then use this 1D array and convert it to 2D as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

A 2D array is not the same object as a 1D array.  The `split` method of String returns a 1D array.

You can assign the result of the split function as an element of the first index of teh 2D array however:

e.g.

```
 int numberOfLines = 10;//Replace with actual count
 int numberOfCols = 10;//Replace with actual count
 String[][] allMyLines = new String[numberOfLines][numberOfColumns]();
 //... iterator stuff
 allMyLines[currentLine] = line.split();
```